# mouseover and dragstart have different target

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dealing with a html with the following format:

`<a href = xxx>
      <div> div1 </div>
      <div> div2 </div>
 </a>`

when I put my mouse over the first div, the target of my mouseover event is the div, but when I drag the div, the target becomes the  tag as a whole. Is there a way to set the target of the drag to the div but not the entire link?

Comment: Need more code than that.

Comment: need more info anyways take a look to stopPropagation();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML seems invalid

> REF: HTML 5 states that the  element "may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)".
>
> #### REF: [Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)

Add `draggable="true"` to the element (HTML5 feature)

> ## draggable
>
> The draggable global attribute is an enumerated attribute that indicates whether the element can be dragged, using the HTML Drag and Drop API. It can have the following values:
>
> **true**, which indicates the element may be dragged
>
> **false**, which indicates the element may not be dragged.
>
> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable

```html
<a href="">
  <div draggable="true"> div1 </div>
</a>
<a href="">
  <div draggable="true"> div2 </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what I really want is to drag the div only but not the entire link. I added draggable = true dynamically on mouseover.

Comment: @WillingBlueberry how about the updated solution? Also, the HTML you have is invalid, you should not wrap clickable element inside `<a>`, check my updated answer for more info